# Are fallback tables a common practice in lua?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have a need to write some Lua code but having come from a C background some of the common practices and programming strategies seem unusual to me. That said I wrote some code that illustrates what I am having trouble with:

```
local someFunction(myName)
  local fallbackTable = {name = ""}    

  local myTable = getTableOrReturnNil(someArgument) or fallbackTable
  local otherName = myTable["name"]
  --other code that is irrelevant
end
```

My question is specifically regarding the line `local myTable = getTableOrReturnNil(someArgument) or fallbackTable`. From what I understand this expression will evaluate to `fallbackTable` if the return value from `getTableOrReturnNil()` return nil. It may be worth mentioning that I do not have control over the function `getTableOrReturnNil()`. Is this a common practice or is there a more standard way to do `local otherName = myTable["name"]` safely without having to worry about if `myTable` is nil. I can resort to using a chain of if's but I would rather avoid this if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fallback values in functions are, especially for optional parameters.  Maybe not *entire tables* as often, but it's not unheard of.

```
local function clamp( value, minimum, maximum )
    minimum = minimum or 0
    maximum = maximum or 255
    return math.min( math.max( value, minimum ), maximum )
end

print(  clamp( -50 ),  clamp( 50 ),  clamp( 500 )  )
```

> 0   50   255

---

---

With tables, you're more likely to see [metatables](https://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.1.html) used when a value isn't present.

```
mytable  = { name = 'nomer' }
meta  = {  __index  = function( tbl, key ) return 'misnomer' end  }

setmetatable( mytable, meta )
print( mytable['name'],  mytable['noname'] )
```

> nomer  misnomer

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/lua/lua_metatables.htm